# Dynamics CRM Getting Account Details

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm having a problem with the following thing.

In Dynamics CRM I have a Custom Button that created a new Order, the button works great, however, I wanted to make it work as the OOB one and prefilled some of the Account information such as Account Name and Price List (form example).

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukfyh.png)

In Ribbon Workbench I've added the following parameter for my button
[ribbon settins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Eoh.png)

The next thing that I've done was to create a new Jscript web resource and add the following code.

references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/customize-dev/pass-dynamics-365-data-page-parameter-ribbon-actions

Web resource name: new_getorder
Code: function XrmCore.Commands.Open.openNewRecord(primaryControl) {

var formContext = primaryControl;

}

I've then added the web resource on the Order form where is supposed to trigger when clicking on the custom button from the account form, but I'm getting a script error (which is not a surprise for me)

[form properies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Eoh.png)

I've also enabled **Pass execution context as first parameter**
Web resource method does not exist: XrmCore.Commands.Open.openNewRecord

[new order button from account ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZWHu.png)

Error when loading the Order form: Web resource method does not exist: XrmCore.Commands.Open.openNewRecord

Comment: Try using parent.XrmCore.Commands.Open.openNewRecord please.

Comment: Can you add picture of ribbon settings? You uploaded form properties twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I've managed to find my solution by using this script in a custom web resource

```
enter code here

var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "salesorder";
entityFormOptions["createFromEntity"] = currentRecordRef;;

// Open the form.
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions).then(
function (success) {
    console.log(success);
},
function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of custom code, why don't you try **Map Entity Field** feature?

> You can map attributes between entities that have an entity
> relationship. This lets you set default values for a record that is
> created in the context of another record.

In your scenario, after mapping Account and Price list fields between Account and Order tables, when you will go to the Related > Orders section and try to create an Order from there, those two fields should be pre-filled on the new Order form.

And I think this feature would work also when you have a Orders sub grid on account form and try to create Order from new button on the sub grid.

[image]

You may go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/map-entity-fields) to understand this concept and to check steps to create mapping.

Comment: Hi Khadim,, these are OOB entities so there is already a mapping between them, what I'm doing here is that I have a custom button in the Account form which when clicked will create a new order for the related Account. However, so far the button only creates new order but without adding the information that is known about the Account, this is the same are create a new order from a sub grid button, but here instead of a subgrid the button is in the form ribbon.

Comment: Well, you can modify the mapping to include price list attribute mapping. That should achieve your desired result, I believe.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you are getting the problem here, the problem is not that the price list field is not mapped, but that custom button open a new form and i'm trying to make it also prefilled information about the original record from where is was selected (in this case is account record)